# How to set the `weight` argument in psych::principal function?

Tags: r, pca, weighted, psych, factor-analysis

I am trying to run an exploratory analysis using PCA to determine the factorial structure of a scale.
The packages I am using are:

```
library(GPArotation) # required for `principal` to work
library(psych)
```

The function is:

```
principal()
```

I would like to apply an adjustment weight based on participants’ gender.

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
GPS_01 GPS_03 GPS_04 GPS_05 GPS_07 GPS_08 GPS_10 GPS_11 GPS_12 GPS_13 GPS_14 GPS_15 GPS_17 GPS_18 GPS_19 gender_pscore
1       1      1      2      2      4      1      3      2      1      1      3      1      2      2      4          0.62
2       1      1      1      1      2      1      1      1      1      1      3      2      3      2      1          2.78
3       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      2      1      2      2      1          0.62
4       1      1      2      2      1      1      1      1      1      1      3      1      1      4      1          0.62
5       4      4      4      4      5      5      4      5      4      4      5      2      5      5      4          0.62
6       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      2      2      3      2      2          0.62
7       1      1      1      1      1      1      2      1      1      1      3      2      4      3      2          0.62
8       1      3      1      1      1      1      3      1      2      1      4      1      4      3      2          0.62
9       3      3      3      5      3      1      4      2      3      1      2      1      5      2      3          0.62
10      1      2      1      1      2      2      1      2      1      2      4      2      2      3      2          0.62
11      1      4      1      1      3      4      1      2      3      1      2      2      3      2      3          0.62
12      1      1      1      1      5      2      1      5      1      3      5      4      5      4      5          0.62
13      1      2      1      1      1      4      1      4      1      3      5      1      4      2      5          0.62
14      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1          0.62
15      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1          0.62
16      1      1      1      1      1      1      2      2      1      1      3      1      1      1      4          0.62
17      2      2      1      2      2      2      4      4      1      4      3      1      2      3      4          0.62
18      1      1      2      2      1      1      1      1      2      1      2      1      2      2      1          0.62
19      1      2      1      1      3      3      1      3      1      1      4      1      3      3      4          0.62
20      1      1      1      2      1      1      2      1      1      1      3      1      2      1      1          2.78
```

or an even smaller subset of your original data (if easier)

```
data<-structure(list(GPS_01 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_03 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_04 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), GPS_05 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), GPS_07 = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_08 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_10 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_11 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_13 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_14 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L), GPS_15 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), GPS_17 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), GPS_18 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L), GPS_19 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), gender_pscore = c(0.62, 
2.78, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here the code I used:

```
pc <-  principal(data[,1:15], nfactors = 3, rotate ="oblimin",weights ="gender_pscore")
```

I always get the same issue:

```
Error in (function (L, Tmat = diag(ncol(L)), gam = 0, normalize = FALSE,  : 
  unused argument (weights = "gender_pscore")
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: Warning message:
In data[,1:20], nfactors = 3, rotate = "oblimin",  :
  The requested transformaton failed, Promax was used instead as an oblique transformation
```

I am quite new to using R, so not sure how to solve this issue.
The problems disappear when I remove the `weights ="gender_pscore"`. But in this case, I can no longer apply an adjustment weight to my factorial analyses based on participants’ gender.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, it will be much easier to help you if you provide a reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10264278. Also, what packages are you using?

Comment: Hi! Thanks Paul. I added some additional info. Hope it is better now

Comment: Have a look at the help file (via `?principal`). You can use `weight` instead of `weights` . That gives a different error, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I did it as well. And, as you said, it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

`weight` seems to be the correct argument for the `principal()` function.
I think the problem comes from the way you told `principal()` to use the column "gender_pscore".

From `?principal` we can read that `weight` is vector of length n.obs that contains weights for each observation. If you use `weight = "gender_pscore"`, you feed a character vector of lenght one into the `weight` argument.

Selecting the column in your data should resolve your problem:

```
psych::principal(df[,1:15], 
                 nfactors = 3, 
                 rotate ="oblimin",
                 weight = df[,"gender_pscore"])
```

**Warning:** this is not a general rule, they are functions that works with quoted or unquoted column names (ex: most tidyverse functions)!

Output of the code above:

```
> psych::principal(df[,1:15], 
+                  nfactors = 3, 
+                  rotate ="oblimin",
+                  weight = df[,"gender_pscore"])
Principal Components Analysis
Call: psych::principal(r = df[, 1:15], nfactors = 3, rotate = "oblimin", 
    weight = df[, "gender_pscore"])
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
         TC1   TC3   TC2   h2      u2 com
GPS_01  0.83  0.13  0.22 0.99 0.01288 1.2
GPS_03  0.83  0.13  0.22 0.99 0.01288 1.2
GPS_04  0.81  0.29 -0.17 0.99 0.00837 1.4
GPS_05  0.81  0.29 -0.17 0.99 0.00837 1.4
GPS_07  0.08  0.88  0.15 0.94 0.05795 1.1
GPS_08  0.83  0.13  0.22 0.99 0.01288 1.2
GPS_10  0.28  0.81 -0.07 1.00 0.00011 1.3
GPS_11  0.63  0.43  0.11 0.99 0.00559 1.8
GPS_12  0.83  0.13  0.22 0.99 0.01288 1.2
GPS_13  0.83  0.13  0.22 0.99 0.01288 1.2
GPS_14  0.69  0.19  0.23 0.83 0.17091 1.4
GPS_15 -0.05 -0.20  1.00 0.95 0.05006 1.1
GPS_17  0.25  0.20  0.81 0.99 0.01386 1.3
GPS_18  1.17 -0.28 -0.23 0.97 0.03065 1.2
GPS_19 -0.01  0.99 -0.13 0.95 0.05381 1.0

                       TC1  TC3  TC2
SS loadings           8.23 3.99 2.31
Proportion Var        0.55 0.27 0.15
Cumulative Var        0.55 0.81 0.97
Proportion Explained  0.57 0.27 0.16
Cumulative Proportion 0.57 0.84 1.00

 With component correlations of 
     TC1  TC3  TC2
TC1 1.00 0.65 0.24
TC3 0.65 1.00 0.19
TC2 0.24 0.19 1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.3
Test of the hypothesis that 3 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.02 
 with the empirical chi square  0.52  with prob <  1 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 1Warning messages:
1: In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
2: In psych::principal(df[, 1:15], nfactors = 3, rotate = "oblimin",  :
  The matrix is not positive semi-definite, scores found from Structure loadings
```

`dput` of `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(GPS_01 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_03 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_04 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), GPS_05 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), GPS_07 = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_08 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_10 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_11 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L), GPS_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_13 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), GPS_14 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L), GPS_15 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), GPS_17 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), GPS_18 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L), GPS_19 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), gender_pscore = c(0.62, 
2.78, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```